# how to save the state of dynamic objects (not included in html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, viewstate

I'm doing a project that involves placing a shape onto a canvas and saving its state to be viewed in another session. Since the shape's color and location are not a part of the source HTML nor are they provided by a form, how can i save it? I've tried storing the shape's data inside an object and then an array, but i dont know how to retrieve this information in another session. Here is the code for the shape:

```
var shapeState = { //Example of a shape being recorded
                            number:increment,
                            id:thisCanvas,
                            type:'shape',
                            kind:shapeKind,
                            cheight:canvasHeight,
                            cwidth:canvasWidth,
                            height:shapeHeight,
                            width:shapeWidth,
                            color:shapeColor,
                            x:xPos,
                            y:yPos
                        }

                        totalState.push(shapeState); //State of shape data has been stored in global array
```

Can anyone help? The fiddle for the entire project is here: http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/5/

Comment: Do you intend the data to be saved such that the same user can continue their session from another computer, or in another browser, as is usual for web apps, or would you be content with tying the storage to the the specific computer and browser that the data was saved from?  In the former case, you would need to do an Ajax request to store your data on the server (somehow). The latter case can be achieved with HTML5 features, as other poster mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers support the [web storage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/); for older ones, you'd use cookies. jQuery has a number of [storage plugins](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/localstorage) that abstract away the specific storage mechanism.